# How to get NuGet/Visual Studio to recognise *_AuthenticodeSigned lib files in a package?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, aspose

So pulling in [version 18.9.0 of Aspose.Cells](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Cells/18.9.0) to a netcoreapp project results in the following error

> warning NU1701: Package 'Aspose.Cells 18.9.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

And if you open that nuget you can see that the netstandard target is suffixed with `_AuthenticodeSigned`.

[image]

If you look at the dependencies in the nuget gallery it lists netstandard2.0 as supported

[image]

So is `_AuthenticodeSigned` a valid convention? If so where is the doco? and how do i get NuGet/Visual Studio to recognise it?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We have been able to notice the problem on our end. An issue with ID CELLSNETCORE-9 is already logged in our issue management system for further investigations. Once, we will have some news for you, we will update you here.

Note: I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: any link to the issue?

Comment: @Simon,
The Issue management system is an internal system and link to logged issue id cannot be shared here. However we have marked it and we will update you here immediately once the issue is resolved and updated dll is available online for download.

Answer (score 0):

@Simon,
This is to inform you that issue with ID CELLSNETCORE-9 is resolved and updated version Aspose.Cells for .NET Core 18.10.0 is available via NuGet Package Manager. You may please try to update the package and provide your feedback.